# Does "Every time someone tries to stop a war before it starts, innocent people die" reference the events of Captain America: The Winter Soldier?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron, history, captain-america-the-winter-soldier

In *Avengers: Age of Ultron* (2015), Captain America says "Every time someone tries to stop a war before it starts, innocent people die." (about 1:14:20) Does this reference the events of *Captain America: The Winter Soldier* (2014)? I'm thinking of this because Captain America says the line and because in *The Winter Soldier*, the helicarriers would have killed millions of innocents who may have posed a threat.

Answer (score 6):

Cap is a WW2 vet.  He may have been thinking of Pearl Harbor.  The Japanese government tried to preempt a war with the US.  Many, many innocent people died as a direct result, at Pearl and throughout the war.  He went into the ice before Hiroshima.  I think he was horrified when he learned about it after he thawed out.

Comment: Have you got any evidence to support this?

Comment: While I personally suspect the answer to original question is just a real world observation of blowback from botched foreign policy.  Regarding Pearl Harbor per history book "Japan 1941" by Eri Hotta it seems Japan's motivation was to deter American interference in their plans for the Pacific and bizarrely a convoluted belief that if dragged into the war the USA would come to it's senses and form a new alliance with Japan against the Soviet Union. (My take on it)